# Replacement for Arduinos millis() that is reliable also with disabled interrupts

Tags: arduino, interrupt, clock

As stated in [stackoverflow-17135805](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135805/does-arduinos-clock-millis-continue-counting-in-the-background-during-interru) the millis() function does not return the correct time, if the interrupts where disabled, while Arduino had to detect an overflow of timer0.

I have a time critical program that uses a lot of functions which have to disable the interrupts. So my program runs 1:30 while it thinks it was running only for 1:00.

Is there another timer that I can use to avoid this problem?

It happens to me when I use the GSM Module:

```
  // startpoint
  unsigned long t = 0;   
  unsigned long start = millis();

  while ( (millis()-start) < 30000 ){
    //read a chunk from the gprs module
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
      client.read();

    //do this loop every 10ms
    while( (millis()-start) < t*10 ){};
    t++;
  }
  //endpoint
```

From the startpoint to the endpoint it should take 30 seconds. Instead it takes 65 seconds.

Comment: Have you measure how much time client.read() is taking along with for loop?

Comment: It is difficult to measure since it can't be done via software.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to disable interrupts so often and so long your best bet would be to use an external timer. I highly recommend DS3231. Since it has a build in crystal it is easier to setup than a 1307 and it is also significantly more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

### You could use one of the other hardware timers

to keep track of the time.  For example, on the Leonardo Timer 1 is a 16 bit timer.

To set it up directly (this obliterates code portability) there are a couple steps.

```
TCCR1A = 0;
```

this puts the timer in "normal" mode, meaning it just runs to 0xFFFF and wraps back to 0x0000.

```
TCCR3B = 0;
TCCR3B = _BV(CS11) | _BV(CS10);
```

this starts the timer and sets it to use a clock/64 prescale, which equates to 1 tic every 4us.

To check the time:

```
long time;        // declared somewhere in scope. 

time = TCNT1;     // this reads the timer count register
time *= 4;        // this multiplies time by 4 to give you us.
```

As mentioned earlier, TCNT1 wraps around at 0xFFFF = 65536.  So, with the pre-scaler set as above, that gives you about 65536 * 4E-6 = .262 seconds of counting before your program needs to put the data into a bigger variable (assuming you care).  Hopefully it isn't a problem to poll things more often than 4 times a second, which gets you away from interrupts.

Several arduino core functions utilize these timers, so you'll need to verify that the core functions you need don't depend on the timer you choose.  For example, doing the above will break analogWrite() on certain pins.